# How to auto generate __unicode__ methods on all my models?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm dealing with some django code in which all models have `__unicode__` methods that look something like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.id) + "; " + ", " + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

(the format in all cases being: print `self.id` and then the rest of the fields separated by commas). What's the best way to clean up this sort of boilerplate? I was thinking of declaring  a `MyModel` class with a `__unicode__` method which lists all fields by inspection, and then having all my current models inherit from `MyModel` instead of the current `django.db.models.Model`. But doing so would change the underlying MySQL tables and I'd hate to have to do such a massive migration for a petty thing like this.

Comment: It needn't change your underlying tables - use an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Kevin Christopher Henry suggested, you could create an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and let all your models inherit that. This would work fine.

However, Python supports multiple class inheritance. This means that a class can inherit from more than one base class. For more information on this subject (and I recommend you read it since it can be tricky) can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

With multiple class inheritance you are able to create a solution that is, at least in my eyes, a lot cleaner. You simply create a class that only has the required code:

```
class PredefinedUnicodeMixin(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id) + "; " + ", " + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

As you might imagine, using this class on its own would not be very helpful. But try this:

```
class MyModel(PredefinedUnicodeMixin, models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Because our mixin class is listed first, it overrides any attributes and methods that are specified in the other classes.

Changing your `__unicode__` method to iterate over the fields is not that hard, `self._meta.get_all_field_names()` should contain all field names.

Of course, on Python 3 you shoud use `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`.